# program execution is too slow in eclipse and was fast just yesterday for the same program

Tags: eclipse, time

I am executing one java program via eclipse and I was executing the exact same program yesterday and my program execution was only taking 10 min yesterday, today the same program is taking more than an hour and I did not change any single thing in my code. could you plwase give me a solution to revert back to the old duration of my program execution that I had yesterday

Answer (score 0):

If you did not change anything in your sourcecode, I see the following possible reasons for this:

- Side-effects on the machine you are running the program on, like other (maybe hidden) processes soak up cpu time and slow down your program.
- This could also be the machine itself being slower (slowdown from to much heat, etc.)
- Your code is doing some "random" things that require longer runs sometimes (sounds unlikely tho)
- Somehow eclipse is causing an issue (try to run your program without it)
- Your java runtime might cause a problem (sounds unlikely aswell, but maybe updating it to the newest version can help)